# Joint lower semicontinuity of the Rényi divergence in all three arguments

Tags: it.information-theory, information-geometry

Let $X$ be a standard Borel space (I'm already interested in the case where $X$ is finite, i.e., $X=\lbrace 1,\cdots,n\rbrace$).  Let $P,Q$ be probability measures on $X$ such that $P\ll Q$. Then the Rényi divergence is defined as
$$
D_\alpha(P,Q) = \frac1{\alpha-1}\log \int_X \Big(\frac{dP}{dQ}\Big)^\alpha~dQ,\qquad \alpha>0.
$$
It is well-known that

1. $D_\alpha(P,Q)$ is jointly lower semicontinuous in $P$ and $Q$ (w.r.t. the weak topology) for all $\alpha>0$
2. $D_\alpha(P,Q)$ is continuous in $\alpha\in (a,b)$ for fixed $P,Q$ if $dP/dQ\in L^\alpha(X,dQ)$ for all $\alpha\in(a,b)$ (which holds for all $a=0,b=\infty$ if $X$ is finite).

My question is: *Is $D_\alpha(P,Q)$ jointly lower semicontinuous in all three arguments $(\alpha,P,Q)$?*

---

**Edit:** Actually, it suffices to show this for $X$ finite.
Indeed, the general case then follows from Theorem 10 in [this review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2459v2) by van Erven and Harremoës, which states that
$$
D_\alpha(P,Q) = \sup_{\mathcal P} D_\alpha( P_{|\mathcal P} , Q_{|\mathcal P}) 
$$
where the supremum is over finite paritions of $X$ and $P_{|\mathcal P}$ denotes the restriction of the measure $P$ to the partition $\mathcal P$ (which is essentially a probability distribution on a finite set).
If we assume lower semicontinuity to be known for finite $X$, then $(\alpha,P,Q) \mapsto D_\alpha(P_{|\mathcal P},Q_{|\mathcal P})$ is lower semicontinuous for each partition.
Now, since lower semicontinuous functions are closed under pointwise suprema, it would follow that $D_\alpha(P,Q)$ is lower semicontinuous in $(\alpha,P,Q)$ as well.

Comment: What is the topology for $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: "It is well-known that ..." -- Can you give references to these assertions?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker the weak topology or the topology of setwise convergence (see the review https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2459 by van Erven and Harremoës). Alternatively the weak topology coming from the dual space $L^\infty(X,dQ)$ of $L^1(X,dQ)$ (see Thm. 3.2 in Hiai's book "Quantum f-divergences in von Neumann algebras")

Comment: @IosifPinelis This is nicely explained in the review paper arxiv.org/abs/1206.2459 by van Erven and Harremoës. The second one can also be seen (except at $\alpha=1$) for continuity of the $L^p$-norm because $D_\alpha(P,Q) = (\alpha-1)^{-1} \log || dP/dQ ||_{L^\alpha(dQ)}^\alpha$.